# What is the best way to pass common variables into separate modules in Node.js?

Tags: design-patterns, node.js

I use separate router files as modules for main app and auth app. I can't get the best way to pass variables(db client) into routers. I don't want to hardcode it or pass it with:

```
module.exports = function(app, db) {
```

Maybe it's best way to use singleton register or use global db variable?

What is your experiense with design-patterns? Which way is the best and why?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931239/how-to-access-variables-declared-in-main-app-js-in-seperate-route-files-in-node/8931366#8931366

Answer (score 110, accepted):

I have found using dependency injection, to pass things in, to be the best style. It would indeed look something like you have:

```
// App.js
module.exports = function App() {
};

// Database.js
module.exports = function Database(configuration) {
};

// Routes.js
module.exports = function Routes(app, database) {
};

// server.js: composition root
var App = require("./App");
var Database = require("./Database");
var Routes = require("./Routes");
var dbConfig = require("./dbconfig.json");

var app = new App();
var database = new Database(dbConfig);
var routes = new Routes(app, database);

// Use routes.
```

This has a number of benefits:

- It forces you to separate your system into components with clear dependencies, instead of hiding the dependencies somewhere in the middle of the file where they call `require("databaseSingleton")` or worse, `global.database`.
- It makes unit testing very easy: if I want to test `Routes` in isolation, I can inject it with fake `app` and `database` params and test only the `Routes` code itself.
- It puts all your object-graph wiring together in a single place, namely the composition root (which in this case is `server.js`, the app entry point). This gives you a single place to look to see how everything fits together in the system.

One of the better explanations for this that I've seen is [an interview with Mark Seeman](http://www.infoq.com/articles/DI-Mark-Seemann), author of the excellent book *Dependency Injection in .NET*. It applies just as much to JavaScript, and especially to Node.js: `require` is often used as a classic service locator, instead of just a module system.

Comment: I'm trying to use this example, however, how do I define my routes in your implementation of Routes.js since it's inside this Routes function? Thanks!

Comment: @cpeele00 the same way you would any other class's methods.

Comment: When using this setup, do you separate out your routes in a similar way? e.g. Routes(app, database) { routes = { social: new SocialRoutes(app, database), api: new ApiRoutes(app, database) }; return routes; }

Comment: I like this style as well.  I built [Electrolyte](https://github.com/jaredhanson/electrolyte), which does exactly this, while eliminating the manual plumbing needed to pass dependencies throughout the application.

Comment: In order to keep a singleton for the whole app is it better to do function App(){...}
module.exports = new App();? If you do this you are caching JUST the new App() and not the function so you can ensure that require() caching will keep your obj a singleton for the whole app. See: http://bites.goodeggs.com/posts/export-this/#singleton

Comment: @alph486 that is the opposite of dependency injection, and I do not recommend it. Singletons are in general an anti-pattern.

Comment: @Domenic - I see your argument in terms of "global scope". But in general this is how spring contexts work isn't it? The framework constructs you an object the way you specify and it is delivered the same way to all callers. The framework also maintains the lifecycle of the objects too. I'm not an expert in node by any means but from what I understand it seems similar. Anyway just a thought. Thanks for the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you create a settings file with db instance and with other things which you need use globally like 'singleton'.

For example, I have settings.js with my redis db client:

```
var redis = require('redis');
exports.redis = redis.createClient(6379, '127.0.0.1');
```

And in other multiple modules I include it:

```
var settings = require('./settings');
setting.redis.<...>
```

Many time including it I always have one instance of db connection.

Comment: If i use next code:
`
var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient(6379, '127.0.0.1');
client.auth(redispass);
exports.client = client;
`
will this module reconnect redis again and again, or not?

Comment: no, only one connection. Look for [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching), _Multiple calls to require('foo') may not cause the module code to be executed multiple times_

Comment: Its risky to rely on "require" for singleton behavior, as you will only get the same instance back if you pass exactly the same path.  The modules are cached based on the passed path, not on a resolved path.  In other words, it will work as a singleton, until you try to use it from a subdirectory.

Comment: @JollyRoger This is not true. Modules are cached based on their resolved filename. See http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_caching_caveats

Comment: @Ilya Ok, technically correct - but it's the resolved filename relative to the calling module, which (per my comment) will be different if you do it from a subdirectory.  So, I stand by my "risky" assessment.

Answer (score 1):

You can save yourself all the boilerplate code of wiring up your modules if you use a dependency injection framework

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20461486/3716153) lists a few of them. I also built a [simpler DI framework here](https://github.com/Gaafar/deppie).

**EDIT:** below is a copy form the answer in case that page changes

---

`require` is **the** way of managing dependencies in Node.js and surely it is intuitive and effective, but it has also its limitations.

My advice is to take a look at some of the Dependency Injection containers available today for Node.js to have an idea on what are their pros/cons. Some of them are:

- [Scatter](https://github.com/mariocasciaro/scatter)
- [Electrolyte](https://github.com/jaredhanson/electrolyte)
- [Wire](https://github.com/cujojs/wire)
- [Intravenous](http://www.royjacobs.org/intravenous/)
- [Pongular](https://github.com/FungusHumungus/pongular)

Just to name a few.

Now the real question is, what can you achieve with a Node.js DI container, compared to a simple `require`?

**Pros:**

- better testability: modules accepts their dependencies as input
- Inversion of Control: decide how to wire your modules without touching the main code of your application.
- a customizable algorithm for resolving modules: dependencies have "virtual" identifiers, usually they are not bound to a path on the filesystem.
- Better extensibility: enabled by IoC and "virtual" identifiers.
- Other fancy stuff possible:

  - Async initialization
  - Module lifecycle management
  - Extensibility of the DI container itself
  - Can easily implement higher level abstractions (e.g. AOP)

**Cons:**

- Different from the Node.js "experience": not using `require` definitely feels like you are deviating from the Node way of thinking.
- The relationship between a dependency and its implementation is not always explicit. A dependency may be resolved at runtime and influenced by various parameters. The code becomes more difficult to understand and debug
- Slower startup time
- Maturity (at the moment): none of the current solutions is **really** popular at the moment, so not so many tutorials, no ecosystem, not battle tested.
- Some DI containers will not play well with module bundlers like Browserify and Webpack.

Answer (score 0):

It is completely outdated, but you can use `global`
in a script :

```
 global.foo = new Foo();
```

in another script :

```
 foo.bar();
```

You can also use already existing constant :

```
 Object.foo = new Foo();
```

And here :

```
 Object.foo.bar();
```