# How to export properly in node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm running some issues with my node application after upgrading to Express 3.0. So, since I'm rewriting it, I was trying to follow the style of `routes/index.js` because it looks clean.

So, in my main `app.js` I have some variables such as:

```
var calls = 0;
var agents = [];
```

And also use the `node-mysql` module. However, the routes definition doesn't have `app.js` scope but their own scope so `calls` and `agents` aren't visible.

How should I make them visible?

For mysql I tried something like:

```
// libraries/mysql.js
mysql = require('mysql');
var mysql_conf = {
    host: myhost,
    user: myuser,
    password: mypass,
    database: mydb
};
var mysql_client = mysql.createClient(mysql_conf);

exports.mysql_client;

//Later in routes/index.js
mysql_client = require('../helpers/mysql.js');
```

But it seems not to work as it says `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'query'`

Any hints please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
exports.mysql_client;
```

Does not actually assign anything to the `mysql_client` property of `exports`. It accesses a property, and immediately discards the value. You need to do something like this:

```
var mysql_client = mysql.createClient(mysql_conf);
exports.mysql_client = mysql_client;

// or simply

exports.mysql_client = mysql.createClient(mysql_conf);
```

Comment: I would also write `module.exports = mysql.createClient(mysql_conf);` Notice the `module`. Just to be safe.

Comment: also: `var mysql_client = module.exports.client = ...` to have a nice local variable.

Comment: That's nice and what about the variables?

Comment: @AntonioLaguna http://stackoverflow.com/q/4140661/139010 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/10306185/139010