# Node modules that instantiate things?

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables

Can I build a module that exports instantiated variables?

Module:

```
var module1 = require('module1')
var Module2 = require('module2')

module1.dosomething(variables)
exports.module1 = module1

//or

module2 = new Modle2(variables)
module2.dosomething(variables)
exports.module2 = module2
```

Can I require the module above in many other files and use the exports as instantiated variables or will they be re-instantiated every time I require them and not shared between the files requiring them.

Thanks!

Comment: You can do either. Not a good answer. It depends on how you want to do it.

Comment: I can do both of those and the exports wont be re-instantiated versons of module1 and module2 each time they are required? The exports will always refer to the already instantiated versions?

Comment: It depends, but yes, see my answer to this other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931239/how-to-access-variables-declared-in-main-app-js-in-seperate-route-files-in-node/8931366#8931366

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example is confusing because you use module1 in multiple contexts, both as a module, a variable within another module, and an exported property of that module.

Think of modules as closures and exports as return values. Most likely you want to export a function/factory function and call that every time if you want to create new instances with the export, anything else will be shared since it just returns the object.

***Module1***

```
module.exports.var1 = function(opts) {
    // do stuff
    return variables;
};

module.exports.var2 = new Blah(); // single instance
```

***Other module***

```
var var1 = require('module1').var1({ opt1: 'foo' }); // New instance every time
var var2 = require('module1').var2; // Same var instance even if you include in another module
```

Answer (score 1):

You can even do things like this to be really annoying. Most npm modules make you create instantiated versions to avoid this kind of silliness.

```
// file.js
var m1 = require('./m1');
m1.awesome = false;
console.log("I am awesome", m1.awesome);

// file2.js
var m1 = require('./m1');
console.log("I am awesome", m1.awesome);

// both.js
require('./file');
require('./file2');

// m1.js
exports.awesome = true;
```

now run this:

```
node file1.js
I am awesome false

node file2.js
I am awesome true

node both.js
I am awesome false
I am awesome false
```

Comment: This basically means in both.js the file1's operations polluted file2 operations right? Meaning we should always export objects that can be instantiated?

Comment: If you return a new object either by doing `new` or by using the factory pattern then yeah you can't collide.